# Create PDF file from HTML and send it to user for signature

Tags: pdf-generation, electronic-signature

I have a HTML form to signup user. After filling that form I want to generate a PDF file from these input and then send that generated PDF to user for signature.

Can anyone help me how can I do this using any Adobe PDF tool.

Comment: Is this a manual process or are you trying to have it automated.  What is the reason for the reference to Adobe tools?

Comment: It will be an automated process. When user will fill the sign up form in our website, server will generate a fix formatted PDF with the information given by user and sent it to user email for his/her signature. After the signature, the signed copy of PDF will be again send to user and stored in our server. Our client like adobe tool, but any good alternative will be also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Once your application has generated the PDF, you can use something like Echo Sign or Docusign to push the PDF into a signature work-flow.  There are lots of systems that can sign the document and many have APIs that you can call, typically along this sequence:

1. Send/Upload the document to be signed
2. Create the details for the signatures to be collected
3. Start the process (kick off the first signature)
4. Listen/respond to notifications of completion of workflow

Your customer may have a preferred system for creating the signatures.  Check the API, have your application make the calls to the document signing service.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### XHTML to PDF

LibreOffice just worked.

1. Make sure you have a form field in your XHTML / HTML code.
2. Open your XHTML / HTML file in LibreOffice.
3. `File`, `Export As` and then `Export as PDF...`/
4. Ensure `Create PDF form` is checked and `Submit format:` is set to `PDF`.
5. Export the PDF.
6. Open the exported PDF and add some text to the form field.
7. Close out your PDF viewer (in my case, Foxit PDF Reader).
8. Your PDF reader *should* ask to save the file, click yes.
9. Open the file again and the text previously added should appear.